# Ionic 3: Ion-select unselect selected option

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a simple ion-select in my template. It is not a mandatory field hence not selecting any option is allowed.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" placeholder ="- Any -">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I have placed a `placeholder="any"` and works just fine until user doesn't select anything. However, once user chooses one of the option and decides not to choose any again, user cannot go back to choosing none. I looked at the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) but couldn't get any clue. Any idea on how can user unselect the option once one of the option has been touched/chosen before?

Comment: You can add a `clear/reset` button right next to that field, and in the click event do something like this: `this.gender = null;`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add a third option of any or whatever you would like it to be

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" placeholder ="- Any -">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="">- Any -</ion-options>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```